Macro for grouping dates from rows - separating groups when date is missing
This is a continuation of the thread that can be found here:
previous question
I slightly edited the macro for myself in the final stage, so I'm pasting the current code here:
Sub GrupingByUser_pop()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, arrFin, firstDate As Date, lastDate As Date
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on D:D
  
  arr = ws.Range("A1:D" & lastR).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")     'set the necessary dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    'if the first columns concatenation does not exist as a key, add it to dictionary:
    If Not dict.Exists(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) Then
        dict.Add CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3), Array(arr(i, 4)) 'the item placed in an array
    Else
        arrIt = dict(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) 'extract the existing item in an array
        ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)                           'redim the item array preserving existing
        arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 4)                                  'place the date as the last array element
        dict(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) = arrIt 'place the array back as the dict item
    End If
  Next i
  
  'redim the final array:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 4)
  
  'process the dictionary data and place them in the final array:
  For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    arrIt = Split(dict.keys()(i), "|") 'split the key by "|" separator
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt): arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrIt(j): Next j   'place each element in its column
    
    firstDate = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(dict.Items()(i)(0))) 'extract first date
    
    arrIt = dict.Items()(i)
    lastDate = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(arrIt(UBound(arrIt)))) 'last date

    If Month(firstDate) = Month(lastDate) Then 'if both date are inside the same month:
       If lastDate = firstDate Then            'if only one date:
            arrFin(i + 1, 4) = firstDate
       Else                                    'if more dates (in the same month)
            arrFin(i + 1, 4) = Format(Day(firstDate), "00") & " - " & Format(lastDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
       End If
    Else                                        'if not in the same month:
       arrFin(i + 1, 4) = Format(firstDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " - " & Format(lastDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End If
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array result, at once:
  Range("P1:T600").ClearContents
  ws.Range("P1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
  
    'sort the range P1:T600 alphabetically by column P
  With ws.Sort
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("P1:P600"), Order:=xlAscending
      .SetRange ws.Range("P1:T600")
      .Header = xlNo
      .Apply
  End With
  
End Sub

Function MakeDateFromStr(d As String) As Date
   MakeDateFromStr = CDate(Mid(d, 4, 2) & "/" & Left(d, 2) & "/" & Right(d, 4))
End Function

This is a macro that, based on data in several columns, groups dates for a specific person and saves them in the form from - to.
Currently, however, the macro does not take into account that there may be a gap in the given set of dates.
The expected result would be as follows:

if a day is missing for a given person in the set, the macro will create two or more rows and split the group into separate intervals.
if there is an empty row with data between the data, then it should skip it, because currently the macro stops and shows error 13.
if the next month starts, the group should also be separated from the previous month

The dates in column [D] are simple text and as a result of the macro operation they have the following format: dd/mm/yyyy or dd-dd/mm/yyyy for groups in the same month (day / month / year - EU) - see example below
Example and expected result in excel for the same month:
Data:

Result:

I left the date justification in the results column as it was originally formatted because it helps me visually separate groups from individual days.

Please post source data as text which can be easily copy/pasted. Your screenshot is as useless here as it was in your original post. This problem is easily solvable with Power Query, available in Excel since 2010

Also, your expected result does not match your description of what you want for an expected result. For example, with regard to GIF KAR, the date span you show in result does includes dates that are not listed in your Data table.

@Ron-Rosenfeld Thank you for the tips, I will try to apply them to the next questions. As for the result, I had to prepare it manually as an example during work and I actually omitted to divide another group. My mistake.

Please, try the next adapted code. It uses a separate function able to interpret the date intervals:
Sub GrupingByUser()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, arrFin
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on D:D
  
  arr = ws.Range("A1:D" & lastR).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")     'set the necessary dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If CStr(arr(i, 1)) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) <> "" Then 'if not an empty row:
        'if the first columns concatenation does not exist as a key, add it to dictionary:
        If Not dict.Exists(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) Then
            dict.Add CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3), Array(arr(i, 4)) 'the item placed in an array
        Else
            arrIt = dict(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) 'extract the existing item in an array
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)                           'redim the item array preserving existing
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 4)                                  'place the date as the last array element
            dict(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) = arrIt 'place the array back as the dict item
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  
  'redim the final array:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 4)
  
  'process the dictionary data and place them in the final array:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    arrIt = Split(dict.keys()(i), "|") 'split the key by "|" separator
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt): arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrIt(j): Next j   'place each element in its column

    arrFin(i + 1, 4) = DateIntervalsSplitMonths(dict.Items()(i)) 'place the calculated interval(s)
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array result, at once and format a little the range:
  Dim rngRet As Range: Set rngRet = ws.Range("P1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
  With rngRet
    .Value = arrFin
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  End With
  PlaceBorders rngRet
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Function MakeDateFromStr(d As String) As Date
   'MakeDateFromStr = CDate(left(d, 2) & "/" & Mid(d, 4, 2) & "/" & Right(d, 4)) 'uncomment for "dd/mm/yyyy"
   MakeDateFromStr = CDate(Mid(d, 4, 2) & "/" & left(d, 2) & "/" & Right(d, 4))  'for localized format "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Function

Function DateIntervalsSplitMonths(arrD) As String 'it calculates the time interval(s)
  Dim frstD As Date, lstD As Date, i As Long
  Dim prevD As Date, follD As Date, strRet As String
  
  frstD = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(arrD(0)))           'extract first date
  lstD = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(arrD(UBound(arrD)))) 'last date
  
  If lstD = frstD Then
    DateIntervalsSplitMonths = frstD               'for one single Date record
  Else                                             'for more than a single data:
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrD)                  'iterate between
            prevD = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(arrD(i)))     'previous Date
            follD = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(arrD(i - 1))) 'following Date
            'if dates are not consecutive OR previous date monts <> followind date monts OR reaches the last array element:
            If prevD <> follD + 1 Or Month(prevD) <> Month(follD) Or i = UBound(arrD) Then
                lstD = IIf(i = UBound(arrD), prevD, follD) 'extract last date in case of last array element or something else
                If Month(frstD) = Month(lstD) Then         'if first date month is the same with last date month
                    strRet = strRet & Format(Day(frstD), "00") & " - " & Format(lstD, "dd/mm/yyyy") & vbLf
                Else
                    strRet = strRet & Format(frstD, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Format(lstD, "dd/mm/yyyy") & vbLf
                End If
                frstD = prevD                        'reinitialize first date as the prvious one
            End If
        Next i
        DateIntervalsSplitMonths = left(strRet, Len(strRet) - 1) 'return strRed - dates interval defined above
  End If
End Function

Sub PlaceBorders(rng As Range) 'new sub able to place borders...
  Dim arrBord, el
  arrBord = Application.Evaluate("Row(7:12)")
  For Each el In arrBord
    With rng.Borders(el)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous: .Weight = xlThin: .ColorIndex = 0
    End With
  Next el
End Sub

The function is also able to interpret dates from two different months, it returns each interval on the cell different line and also splits continuous dates intervals per months...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

@KMYozz You, probably will need to swap month with day from the string data, as in the previous case, but this looks to mean that your localized standard time is not as you said ("dd/mm/yyy"), it probably is of format "mm/dd/yyyy"... I did not post the MakeDateFromStr function (on purpose), so you need to use the former one.

Thank You. It's a new month so I have to wait a few days to get new data where there will be some gaps and I'll test the code. At the moment I don't see anything wrong. The dates are displayed ok. I've corrected the main post because I inserted the code from the wrong macro (I don't know what I was thinking, I was probably distracted and my vacation is still a long way off). To Your code I only added sorting to suit my needs in the final phase.

I only have one question/request: is it possible to create a new row for the same employee for a new group? Now if an employee has 2-3 groups, they are separated by commas in one cell and visually they merge in the eyes.

@KMYozz Everything is possible it it is logically explained, but it was good to mention this requirement in the question... The algorithm of group extracting should be different and it is complicated toReDim the necessary arrFin,  not knowing how many such groups will exist after processing. I do not like using ReDim Preserve many time, since it is wrong from the memory handling point of view. I would propose a different approach, visually leading to the same visual effect. I mean, to place each group in only one cell, but on the different lines. Wouldn't it be OK?

@KMYozz  Adapted the above code. In the function I only replaced the concatenation characters (", ") with vbLF and in the main sub added some code lines to format the range where the array is returned. To autofit columns/rows and used VerticalAlignment = xlCenter, to make the range looking nice and ease to observe which is which...

@KMYozz In the meantime I created a new Sub able to place borders around each cell, to emphasize the visual aspect even more... Adapted the code to contain it. In order to easily use it I also placed MakeDateFromStr (adapted for your localized date format), so you can copy everything overwitting existing...

Sorry, but I mention this in "1. [...] the macro will create two or more rows and split the group into separate intervals".  Tomorrow, at work I will check it all. I don't have view to files from home right now, but I think it will be ok. Thank You for Your time.

@KMYozz Yes, you said that and I tried explaining why it is simpler how I proposed, obtaining the same visual effect and having a faster code. Anyhow, I almost finished the function after you wrote the new requirement... Also because of that my code splits/extracts only the continuous intervals. You said that a second month will not exist. I made that part as bonus... I mean, if the interval starts on 30.07.2024 and finishes on 02.08.2024 it will be returned in the same interval... If you really need splitting even a continuous interval, if it contains two months I can do it.

@KMYozz I found some time and adapted the function to also split the date intervals by months. Please send some feedback after testing it.

Thank you again for your time. I was offline for a while, I have a few audits behind me, so I have a moment of respite to think at least in the evening about how to make it easier to process repetitive data. I test it on smpl data and it seems to me that in some cases the macro groups incorrectly. I'm attaching a link to a sample file (wetransfer) and in it I've circled three sample people in red text, and on a yellow background the ranges of days that have a break between them and should be separate but are connected.

ps. I used first code for MakeDateFromStr The macro modified in the final phase is in the example file. I did not change the main part. LINK: link.

@KMYozz Firstly, I would like to apologize for my previous comments (deleted, now). It was a confusion... I was in  a conversation with somebody else, not knowing very well what he really needs and after receiving some samples and sending  back the files with code to fulfil his requests he did not replay anything for a long period of time. When I found your answer and download the file I was convinced that it is from him. That's why that comments... Now he replied with different (childish) requests and I observed that my comments were missing. Looking after the last comments I reached here.

@KMYozz Now the link it is not valid, anymore. I think I have the downloaded file, but now (and in weekend) I am and I will be very busy, so I cannot look on it very soon. I will do it on Tuesday. If I will find some time I will try looking on it sooner. Sorry, again...

@KMYozz I could not stay until leaving my office, so I looked at the data in the file. I moved what you sent (with yellow highlights) on the other sheet and now tried comparing the result. I did not adapt anything in the code. I only filtered in a different way the range to be processed (if it is ok, I will include this part in the code). I am looking to what the code returns and it looks OK to me. Please, download the workbook form here and try clarifying the issue. Is it something I am missing. Some time passed and I maybe do not remember very well the goal...

@KMYozz Did you sent the previous code return or what you wont? Now, not having your original file, I do not what to understand...

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//ConvertS Date strings to real dates if they are not
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Column3", type nullable date}},"en-150"),

//Add index column to help in grouping
    #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type","Index", 0,1,Int64.Type),

//Uses optional 4th and 5th arguments to define the groups so as to 
//create the "islands and gaps"
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Index", {"Column1", "Column3", "Index"}, {
        {"Span", each if Table.RowCount(_) = 1 then Date.ToText([Column3]{0}, "      dd.MM.yyyy")
            else Date.ToText(List.Min([Column3]),"dd-"
                     & Date.ToText(List.Max([Column3]),"dd.MM.yyyy")), type text}
        },
        GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(
             Duration.Days(y[Column3]-x[Column3]) <> (y[Index]-x[Index])
              or y[Column1]<>x[Column1]
              or Date.StartOfMonth(y[Column3])<>Date.StartOfMonth(x[Column3])
            )
        ),

//Remove unneeded columns and rows
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Column3", "Index"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null})))
in
    #"Removed Blank Rows"


